# Generating pdf files using PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am trying to generate pdf file  using pace automation framework. Could you please tell me how to generate pdf file .Is there any tag in PAF to generate PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

**PDF tag** can be used to generate PDF files based on an existing template and input data.

Attributes:filename,targetFolder,fontName,fontSize,font,template,mapping

```
Example:<pdf fileName="" targetFolder="" fontName="" fontSize="" font="./pdf/TimesNew Roman 400.ttf.ttf"
template="./pdf/pdf_template.pdf" mapping=""></pdf>
```